# Is there a way to get rid of this painting issue in the TListView control?

Tags: delphi, vcl, tlistview

I am using XE5 Update 2 on windows 7 64 bit (all the updates up-to-date).

I have an app with a simple TListView object.

```
object lsvReceipts: TListView
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Width = 1382
  Height = 760
  Align = alClient
  Columns = <
    item
      Caption = 'Column 1'
      Width = 100
    end
    item
      Caption = 'Column 2'
      Width = 100
    end
    item
      Caption = 'Column 3'
      Width = 100
    end
    item
      Caption = 'Column 4'
      Width = 100
    end>
  MultiSelect = True
  OwnerData = True
  RowSelect = True
  TabOrder = 0
  ViewStyle = vsReport
  OnData = lsvReceiptsData
  ExplicitLeft = 136
  ExplicitTop = 200
  ExplicitWidth = 521
  ExplicitHeight = 321
end
```

Here is some of the pas code. It simply displays the data from a firedac TFDQuery object.

```
procedure TForm3.lsvReceiptsData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
var index: integer;
begin

 index := Item.Index;
 receiptsQuery.RecNo := index;
 Item.Caption := dockReceiptsQueryDR_.AsString; 
 Item.SubItems.Add(receiptsQueryDOCK_RCPT_ID.AsString);
 Item.SubItems.Add(receiptsQueryRCVD_DATE.AsString);
end;
```

As you can see in the image below, there are some repainting problems that occur when I select a few rows and then I deselect them. If I set the OwnerData to false and add the records to the list manually using the lsvReceipts.Items.Add method it doesn't happen.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this? Based on other messages I've seen here, the control is riddled with issues. Unfortunately, I have to use it for now.

And in case you are wondering, I need a list with several columns, where the user can select multiple records. I begun by using a DBGrid with the multiselect option set, however, after using it for a bit the functionality for selecting multiple rows is limited (for instance, SHIFT+Click, SHIFT+PageUp/PageDown don't work). We plan to upgrade to the devexpress grid in the future anyway, but for now I have to stick to the vcl vanilla controls.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: @Graymatter: There is no OnDrawItem code. I don't implement that event. Should I?

Comment: Not quite a fix but it may be worth looking at the OnDrawItem as you can paint the items yourself. Another alternative is to look at TVirtualStringTree (https://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/) which does a similar thing when used in grid mode and the full row selection enabled. If you look at the page in the Advanced demo and enable the toFullRowSelect option then you will be able to see what it looks like.

Comment: Set `DoubleBuffered` on your list view. If you can't for any reason, refer to previous comment.

Comment: That's very odd. I use the same control in exactly the way you describe and don't see the issue. I'll take a look later.

Comment: This is very odd. My control, seemingly the same as yours, does not behave like that

Comment: @David - In the link I've posted, you seem to have duplicate it.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes, I noticed. Cannot do it again though.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies - setting DoubleBuffered=true fixes this issue. I did search so for the issue but I did not find this article specified by Sertac. I am going to vote for closing the question.